# how to remove non-readable character in SMS in java

Tags: java, regex, sms, non-ascii-characters

The SMS looks like this:
¿`´10 he did't wo¿`^rk.

The expected result is:
10 he did't work.

how to do that in Java?

thanks you.

Comment: And what tells you that those characters are indeed "unreadable"? It may very well be that you didn't encode properly...

Comment: try str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")

Comment: @NayanSharma that's not valid Java syntax and the regex wouldn't be sufficient anyways (it doesn't include digits and other special characters - using it you'd get "he didt work").

Comment: Is there any solution without specifically mentioned specific character in regex? the data is coming from SMS. i believe this chacterter '¿´' meant something. TQ.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
String result = "¿´10 he did't wo¿^rk".replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\?'':;]","");
System.out.println(result); //10 he did't work
```

Please see this link for [explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cXM532/1)

Comment: Is there any solution without specifically mentioned specific character in regex? the data is coming from SMS. i believe this chacterter '¿´'  meant something. TQ.